# How to create negative primary keys in java hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a table in which data is inserted from two different sources with their own primary key generation techniques. So, there is a strong possibility that primary key conflict happens. We want to make one of the sources to create negative primary keys using hibernate to prevent such conflict. Is it possible? and How? Thank you in advance

Comment: What will you do when a third source comes in? Why not use a standard generation strategy (sequence, identity, table, uuid), that does support any number of sources without any problem?

Comment: we do use sequence generation strategy in one of the sources. The problem is, two different, separated sources, each have their own strategies which are not aware of each other. So, they both create positive primary keys.

Comment: But you're ready to change the strategy, since that's what you're asking for. So just use the same sequence-based strategy everywhere (with the same sequence of course), and you're done.

Comment: Or if that is really not possible expand the primary key with a "source" identifier column. That adds the bonus that you know from the record where the data came from.

Comment: well basically you throw that overhead to the database itself , so the database will be responsible to generate the unique keys and not each java app you want to connect. So you might have to re-design your key generator. Also you havent pointed out which DB you are using

Comment: thanks for your responses. But, we solved the problem. For more clarification I have to say that in our system 2 different usecases insert into one table, one within a database procedure and another through java hibernate transactions. So we changed sequences in procedure to create negative IDs. This way, 2 sets of primary keys, each for one different usecase are created, which are easily recognizable, as one of them is negative and another one is positive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a generation with negative number here is a way 
 in your database

```
 create sequence SEQ_ACE_WORKERS
       MINVALUE -100 
       MAXVALUE 1 
       START WITH -99
       INCREMENT BY 1 
        ;
```

And in your hibernate class you change the strategy to "sequence".
But i think to go further that you should really use the same sequence for the two sources